# in a select statement - how to include a filter after a function b4 the from clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select the top sales person by 'location & Product' combination.
1st I Sort & Rank, then I sum for "Location & Product", then I want to drop all but the top sales person by "Location & Product" such that the query result contains only The Top Salesperson by "Location & Product" with the total sales for each "Location & Product" combination.

The one part I don't have is the "select Rank = 1" - adding a "where" clause after "From" does not work:

```
Select Location, Product, Sales, Salesperson
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY concat(Location,Product) ORDER BY Sales desc) AS Rank,
       Sum(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY concat(Location,Product)) AS Salesbylocprod
From Table A
```

Comment: You put your current query in a subquery, and then select only the values from that subquery where rank = 1 (e.g. `select * from (my current query) as t where rank = 1;`). As a side note, using `CONCAT` in your `PARTITION BY` clause seems unnecessary; you can partition by both columns anyway for the same result (and in some unique scenario where a concatenation of two different locations and products is the same, you'd avoid that scenario).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery.  Also, you don't need to concatenate keys for the `partition by`:

```
Select Location, Product, Sales, Salesperson, Salesbylocprod
from (select a.*
             row_number() over (partition by Location, Product order by Sales desc) as seqnum,
             sum(Sales) over (partition by Location, Product) as Salesbylocprod
      From Table A
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that I changed the name of the column from `rank` to `seqnum`.  `rank` would sort of imply that it is calculated using the `rank()` function.  That is different from `row_number()` so the name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Common Table Expressions:

```
;WITH CTE 
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location,Product ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS RowNum,
                SUM(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY Location,Product) AS SalesByLocProd
         FROM TableA
        )
        SELECT Location,
             Product,
             Sales,
             SalesPerson,
             SalesByLocProd
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RowNum = 1;
```